# How can I use Index Match as Worksheet Functions?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a variable named 'searchVal' that is generated dynamically.  Now, I'm trying to pass this string into Index/Match, and I'm getting tripped up somewhere.  Maybe it's some kind of double-quotes thing, but I tried that and it still didn't work.

Here is my non-working function.

```
ID = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets(""360Tasklist"").Range(""B2:B1000""), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(" & searchVal & ", Sheets(""360Tasklist"").Range(""C2:C1000""), 0), 0)
```

This isn't right either.

```
    ID = "Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets(""360Tasklist"").Range(""B2:B1000""), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(" & searchVal & ", Sheets(""360Tasklist"").Range(""C2:C1000""), 0), 0)"
```

I must be close though...  Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: try ID = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("360Tasklist").Range("B2:B1000"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(searchVal, Sheets("360Tasklist").Range("C2:C1000"), 0))

Comment: That worked.  I didn't even think about it.  I just assumed you always put quotes around those things and then tie them together with a couple && characters.

Comment: Quotes are only put around direct references, so no need for the extra "". But you were close with your formula.